# Featured image size changing when uploaded

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I'm developing a WordPress theme. But I have problem in post thumbnail to set featured image. When I set a featured image with 300x210 px then it becomes 221x155. In functions.php, I added this code. Is it an issue with the CSS file?

```
//add support for featured images 
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(300, 210);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a `true` and the `if` statement. Replace your function.php code with this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 320, 210, true );
}
```

Also, this code should be replacing the original `set_post_thumbnail_size` in the functions.php (set by the theme).